# How to debug failing xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve data from a database on my server to use client-side. It is failing without appearing to actually throw any errors and I can't figure out how to debug it.

My server is written in node.js/express with a MongoDB database and looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');

var Sample = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.setupVariables = function() {
        self.ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
        self.port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

        if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
          connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
          process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
          process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
          process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
          process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
        }
        console.log(connection_string)
    };

    self.createRoutes = function() {
        self.routes = { };

        self.routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
        };

        self.routes['/testdata'] = function(req, res) {
          console.log('Got request for testdata')
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

          MongoClient.connect('mongodb://'+connection_string, function(err, db) {
            if(err) throw err;
            var collection = db.collection('TestData').find().limit(10).toArray(function(err, docs) {
              if(err) throw err;
              res.send(docs);
              db.close();
            })
          })
        }
    };

    self.initializeServer = function() {
        self.createRoutes();
        self.app = express();
        ['js'].forEach( function(dir) {
          self.app.use('/'+dir, express.static(__dirname+'/'+dir));
        })

        //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
        self.app.get(function(req, res, next) {
          console.log('Got request:', req);       // used to debug
          next();
        });

        for (var r in self.routes) {
            self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
        }
    };

    self.initialize = function() {
        self.setupVariables();
        self.initializeServer();
    };

    self.start = function() {
        self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress)
        });
    };
var myapp = new Sample();
myapp.initialize();
myapp.start();
```

My client side (index.html) code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // Get data from server
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://my.example.com/", true);
    xmlHttp.send( "/testdata" );
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
        var data = xmlHttp.responseText

        window.onload = function() {
          document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = data
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <p id="p1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to get data from the database to use on the html page. I am trying to do that by issuing an `xmlhttprequest` to get `/testdata` from the server. Then I thought the server should route that request to the appropriate function. But when I run this (well, the version with lots of other extraneous stuff that I deleted for this post), the request just sits there with `xmlHttp.status=1`.

Two options for answers:
1) What is wrong?
2) How do I even go about debugging this problem? The server is hosted remotely so I don't think I can use a tool like node-inspector.

Comment: 1. Do you get your expected database data when you hit your testdata URL in a browser? 2. I think you are misunderstanding how to use the XHR `send()`. It's for actually sending data, like in a POST, PUT or DELETE. You want to actually have `/testdata` part of your URL in the `open()` call.

Comment: I think your `window.onload` handler is never executed because it is set after the onload event occurs (the ajax call happens after the load event, I believe). Also, use `console.log` to troubleshoot results within your `onreadystatechange` xhr handler.

Comment: @M.AdamKendall 1. Yes, the data comes through correctly that when I access it at the direct url. 2. I think you were right on. After looking at more examples, I went back and changed it to `xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://my.example/testdata/", true);
xmlHttp.send();` and its working! Thanks! If you want to post the answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Sebas Yes, that was also a problem, but not the critical one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how to use the XHR `send()`. It's for actually sending data, like in a POST, PUT or DELETE. You want to actually have `/testdata` as part of your URL in the `open()` call, and use just `.send()`.